# Akka get context with Behaviors.withTimers

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-typed

Using **Behaviors.withTimers** any idea how can we obtain the context, to use the **context.log** of Akka?

Normally I use when I define the Behavior with

```
Behaviors.setup { context =>
```

But with

```
Behaviors.withTimers
```

It seems it cannot be combined.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

With this:

```
Behaviors.setup { context =>
      Behaviors.withTimers { timers => 
         context.log.debug("")
   }
}
```

should work.

Comment: I found the issue I had to add the types in the setup, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding the type works

```
Behaviors.setup[T] { context =>
      Behaviors.withTimers { timers => 
         context.log.debug("")
   }
}
```